# How can I use an if statement to use two time values in one string to change cell colors?

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I am trying to write a code using vba that allows me to automatically create a schedule in excel that changes grey squares to white squares based on hours scheduled.  The sheet contains a column of the names of all the employees working on a particular day with a cell next to it showing what hours they are working. Then there is a column for each hour that our business is open from 8am to 9pm.  The hours show as a text string that reads exactly (for example) "12:00p-8:00p" so I need to make the the cells in that row from 12pm to 8pm turn white (they are default grey).  So it would read something like this (G being grey and W being white):

First cell contains employee name.   Second hours scheduled.  Next 13 cells = hours we are open.

|Sam Smith|12:00p-8:00p|G|G|G|G|W|W|W|W|W|W|W|W|G|

So when I import my weekly schedule into the appropriate cells, I need to be able to click a button that automatically turns those cells grey or white depending on the two different values in the text string, which is where I can't seem to get any help, I need excel to somehow know for instance that I need my if statement to say basically if the first time in the text string is '12:00p' then anything greater than that should be a white cell but only until the '8:00p' in the text string, which is way beyond my expertise.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  If this is already covered and I missed it a link would be great, but I can't seem to find it, thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to have :30 times as well? (ex: 12:30p) Would it be difficult for you to make it 24 hours instead? It would simplify it marginally (but not that much, however 12:00-20:00 is easier to handle). To answer you partially , you can use the Instr("12:00p-8:00p", "-") function to return the place where the "-" occurs. Then use Left, right or mid functions to extract the beggining time and the ending time. What follows will depend on your answer to the first 2 questions.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response I have replied to both you and Luis below.

Answer (score 0):

Thats right, just as David GM said, its easier if you use a 24 hours schedule so you can use left(Schedule,2) to get the first hour and left(right(schedule,5),2) to get the second hour, then you could use a cicle:

```
x = left(Schedule,2)
l = column where your first (8) hour is (number)
y = line where your first employee is
l = l+ (x - 8) (since you are starting from 8)
while x <= left(right(schedule,5),2)
     Cells(l,y).format = backgroundcolor you want
     l = l+1
     x = x+1
loop
```

something like that should do it, i am not using the exact sintaxis since i am not able to test it right now, but that's the main idea

Comment: Thank you both for your prompt responses and info, unfortunately both have :30 times (I had totally forgot to include that).  I suppose the second part isn't as big of a deal as I could have the users just change those manually if needed or perhaps even write a second script that exports to a new file and changes those 24 hours to a 12 hour clock format?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is an attempt. I'll be using the 24 hour format. If you want to know how to switch between one and the other, you can probably find that elsewhere or make a post about that.

```
sub schedule() 
    dim i as integer 'this is for a loop
    dim nb_employees as integer 'this is to count the number of rows to loop on assuming 1 row is 1 employee
    dim strTime as string
    nb_employees = [sheetname].Cells(Rows.Count, "[column where the employees are listed]").End(xlUp).Row - [starting row]

    for i = 1 to nb_employees 'will loop the right amount of times
        strTime = range("[column with the times]" & i + [starting row]).value 'strTime will contain the hours 
        call displaySchedule(strTime, i + [starting row])
    next
End sub
```

That sub will feed the next one, which takes in what employee is being treated (i + [starting row]) as well as his schedule.

```
sub displaySchedule[time as string, row as integer]
```

It will break down the string to extract the starting/ending time. It will substract them to see how many hours will be worked. Say employee works 12 to 20, so 8 hours worked. Will grey out the cell that corresponds to (row, [column that is 12h in your excel sheet]) and with a loop, go to the next cell, do the same, go to the next, do the same 8 times because you calculated 8 hours. Then the sub ends, and it will return to the first sub I wrote for you for the next employee. I'm sorry if i didn't write the second sub down but I didn't have the time (plus Stack Overflow isn't quite made for a complete service like that ;) ). I hope you can use my idea to work something out, though.

Note that the first isn't tested and may need to be fiddled with a bit.